# How to edit a txt file in python

Tags: python, file, text, edit, txt

I have a folder containing text files like this:

```
3 0.39453125 0.49609375 0.017578125 0.0302734375
1 0.4130859375 0.5029296875 0.0224609375 0.025390625
5 0.8125 0.46875 0.1123046875 0.0849609375
0 0.4677734375 0.5078125 0.0283203125 0.0380859375
```

The first digit is the class. How can I make it so that only lines belonging to class 0 and 1 remain in the files?

So in the end it should look like this:

```
1 0.4130859375 0.5029296875 0.0224609375 0.025390625
0 0.4677734375 0.5078125 0.0283203125 0.0380859375
```

I tried this:

```
for file in os.listdir(folder):
  with open(file,"r+") as f:
      new_file = f.readlines()
      f.seek(0)
      for line in new_file:
          if line.startswith('0') or line.startswith('1'):
              f.write(line)
      f.truncate()
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What do you suppose are the logical steps to solving the problem? Did you try to write code to implement these steps? Where exactly are you stuck - what don't you know how to do?

Comment: I added my code to the question just now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**i hope this works for you :)**

```
file = open("text.txt", "r+")

text_list = [line for line in file.readlines() if line.split()[0] in ["0", "1"]]

file.truncate(0)
file.seek(0)
file.write("".join(text_list))
file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code should only return line 0 and 1 in an array called write.

```
write = []   
with open("test.txt",'r',encoding = 'utf-8') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line[0] = '1' or line[0] = '0':
          write += [line]
```